# Recreate an existing table in google big query

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

Basically what I want to do are as follows:

1. Check if a table already exists in bigquery
2. If Table does not exist, then there is no issue. It will create a new table and insert rows
3. If table already exists, then I need to drop the existing table, create a new table with different schema with same name and then insert new rows in the newly created table

   ```
     const gbqConnection = await GbqConnection.findOne({ spreadSheetId }).lean();
     const bigquery = new BigQuery({
       projectId: gbqConnection.credentials.project_id,
       credentials: gbqConnection.credentials
     });

     const dataset = bigquery.dataset(gbqConnection.schema);
     let table = dataset.table(gbqConnection.table);

     const [existingTable] = await table.exists();
     if (existingTable) await table.delete();

     const newTableName = `${gbqConnection.table}`;


     const gbqSchema = headers.map((header) => {
       const newObject = {
         name: header.name,
         type: gbqDataTypeMapping[header.headerType.datatype]
       };
       return newObject;
     });

     let newTable = await dataset.createTable(newTableName, {
       schema: gbqSchema
     });

     const skipField = ["-order", "-isDeleted", "-createdAt", "-updatedAt", "-spreadSheetId", "-_id"];
     const rows = await SpreadSheetRow.find({
       spreadSheetId,
       isDeleted: false
     }).sort({ order: 1 }).select(skipField.join(" ")).lean();
     const [job] = await newTable.insert(rows);
     console.log('inserted Rows jobbbbb', job);

     return rows;
   } catch (err) {
     throw err;
   }
   ```

   }

I have tried multiple ways to do so. Some of them are as follows:

1. I tried dropping old table and directly creating new table with same name. In this case, when I try to insert rows in newly created table, it throws error that table does not exist
2. I tried dropping old table and creating a new table with new name. After inserting rows in new table, I cannot rename this table. It throws streaming data error and does not allow me rename table.